# Terminating cat 6 at patch panel

Tags: networking, cable, cat6

My patch panel does not have pin marking so I am not sure what pins 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. This is what my panel patch looks like:

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35kq61x&s=8#.VaR2U0r3arU]

This is termination that was already done in the house but from observation I am not sure if this is T568A or T568B and to me it doesn't look like any of these two.  My other and is terminated at keystone using T568B.

To try I terminated exactly as these two and I tested it using a network tester and this is what the tester showed:

http://youtu.be/q9CH1TzLx2I

Can anyone help with this please? Does anyone have an idea what the pin numbers are on my patch panel?

Comment: That's not a Cat patch panel.... a cat5/6 one uses 8 wires, not 4 as used in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that patch panel doesn't look like it was designed for 8x8 ethernet. The numbering seems to assume you are going to use a 4x4 jack such as for a digital-telephone system? Your video is too dark to tell what is blinking on the tester.

I'd try to sent a signal to all pairs and just make sure you are getting something on each individual wire on the other end (wall jack). If you are, then just patch it down like you see in your picture: blue/white, blue, orange/white, orange, green/white green, brown/white, brown (1-8 or 8-1)

Comment: How do i sent signal to all pairs.  I am sorry i don't understand what you mean. How do i test each individual wire? Wires and settings that i have found in the house as per that picture works fine and tests fine. Now something is wrong with my r

Comment: Sorry i submitted by error without finishing. Now something is wrong with my termination either at my keystone or my parch panel termination. My keystone is standard B which has pin 1,2 white/orange orange etc.   where are on my patch panels pins 1,2.  If i can locate them i would terminate pin 1 with white/orange and pin 2 orange but i don't have clue of pin numbers on this patch panel

Comment: I should have said tone: http://youtu.be/jP0AtN9hTP4 You basically want to make sure the cable wires on the walljack are the ones you think they are on the patch panel (say 8 wires on patch panel labels 3 & 4). I understand your keystone is T568B, however somebody did it wrong at the patch panel. So you either yank the cords there & do it right, or mimic it on other end. Patch panel label 3 (pin 1)=white/blue so on wall jack/keystone it'd go to pin 1. I assuming patch panel labels 3 & 4 are wires 1-8 on your wall jack. I think you are confusing the patch panel labels for pin #'s, they are not!

Comment: This is what I have right now http://tinypic.com/r/zy5xt2/8

Comment: ok i think i get what you saying. If i try to mimic patch panel at the keystone end. As you said label 3 pin 1 = white/blue i should go to keystone and terminate in pin 1 (keystone) white/blue as well even thought by either standard a or b pin 1 should have white/green (standard a) or white/orange (standard b)

Comment: I guess whoever did it right, per the spec page it's T568-A in 110 punch-down blocks: http://www.hubbellcatalog.com/hubbellpremise/datasheet.asp?PN=NSODM8&FAM=netselect
http://www.vdvworks.com/VHO/utpterm/cat5pd-2.htm
http://tombuildsstuff.blogspot.com/2015/02/x16-phone-110-wiring-diagram.html

Comment: Ok so i will try to match this order on the keystone.  How do i pull out wires from my already punched down keystone? Do i need to use new keystone or i can reuse this one?

Comment: I think this picture might clear BOTH of our heads: http://www.lanshack.com/cat5e-tutorial.aspx  As for your question: I am not sure. I'd imagine you can remove the wires just by pulling them up, just make sure no sheathing (the stuff covering the copper) is left. I'd imagine the keystone pin is only so sharp so can only do a couple times. I'd also recommend cutting the wire & starting fresh since keystone slices a bit from it making it NOT-AS-SOLID a connection as originally (although may work)

Comment: Best of luck, I am heading to bed myself, please upvote or mark my response as the answer if you believe it helped!

Comment: Now when i looked at this last one this is standard again a and b.  Do you still think white/blue on patch panel is pin 1 that should be matched to the keystone?

Comment: It's possible! I wish that dang patch panel had pin numbers or manual for it did; maybe on the back side of it!? That is where a toner comes in handy to send signal. Ghetto trick I have used in my house: plugin Ethernet with one end crimped to patch panel, connect 9V to blue/white, blue on open/non-crimped end of Ethernet cable from patch, go to walljack & use voltmeter to test pairs for voltage

Comment: I matched the pins on keystone and patch panel and only 4 pins tested good. I know number of pins that dont test but how do i know if error on the pin is at keystone end or patch panel?

Comment: Why am i terminating these at ptch panel.    Cant each end on my cable be plug.  Then one end to my tv and other end in the back of the router?

Comment: Ok i think i am good now.  I pulled one end out of that patch panel.  I terminated one end at keystone and the other end has a plug.  I tested it and it looks good.  I plugged plug end in the one of the router ports and using patch cable (connected to keystone) i connected my laptop. Everything works.  I used standard B. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Good job, yeah at my house I didn't use a patch panel (I just did keystone wall jack to cable like you). Its nice to do so you can have the jacks marked (to match the wall jack), more permanent & solid connection with ability for longer cable off patch (although one could argue you could use a coupler piece). I am glad you got it done. Would you mind uprooting to marking as answer?

Comment: How dp i do that? To upvote you need 15 reputatuons it says?

Comment: Tis true, I forget. You CAN accept (checkmark) the answer though & I believe that ALSO gives you points to